# Apart from some Product pages,my whole Application was working fine on Katalon studio,what is the proper solution?

Tags: katalon-recorder

i will get some exception

Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException:

Comment: You need to give us some code and error message you're dealing with.

Comment: est Cases/Test_02 FAILED.
Reason:
com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/TC_MY02/a_NEW'
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.ClickKeyword.click(ClickKeyword.groovy:86)